# Add minutes to Current Specified time

Tags: c#, time, addition

I want to add 5 minutes to specified time here is my code below.

```
string startTime = "1:00 AM";
string endTime = "0:05 AM";

TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(endTime).Add(DateTime.Parse(startTime));
```

I keep getting error how can I had 5 minutes on to 1:00 AM to become 1:05 AM?

Comment: Add the error message to the question

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a time, you can only add a span. However, you can get the span of a DateTime through the `TimeOfDay` property:

```
string startTime = "1:00 AM";
string endTime = "0:05 AM";

DateTime duration = DateTime.Parse(startTime).Add(DateTime.Parse(endTime).TimeOfDay);
```

However, directly using a timeSpan is more recommendable (you have to remove the `AM`, as it is a span and not a DateTime):

```
string startTime = "1:00 AM";
string endTime = "0:05";

DateTime duration = DateTime.Parse(startTime).Add(TimeSpan.Parse(endTime));
```

If you know that you'll never going to add something else than minutes, I'd do something like this:

```
string startTime = "1:00 AM";
int minutes = 5;

DateTime duration = DateTime.Parse(startTime).AddMinutes(minutes);
```

You can learn more about DateTime [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: +1.  Offset, think about the program conceptually.  You *don't* have a start time and an end time.  You've got a start time and a *duration*.  What you really want is 'startTime' as a string, and 'durationInMinutes' as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the whole `DateTime` object, while you need to pass only the `Minute` property after parsing the `endTime` string and then use the `AddMinutes` method on the parsed `DateTime` object of `startTime` for this :

```
DateTime updateTime = DateTime.Parse(startTime).AddMinutes(DateTime.Parse(endTime).Minute);
```

It will return the `DateTime` object adding 5 minutes to the original `DateTime` object i.e. **1:00 AM** and the reuslt would be **1:05 AM**

See the working [DEMO Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pXbiDA)

Comment: No, no - this is a bad idea.  This code works... until the duration changes to something that isn't an integer number of minutes between 1-59.  If the duration changes to 30 seconds or to a whole hour?  Then this code would add 0 minutes to the start time.

Answer (score 1):

The Add method has an overload which gets TimeSpan. Use it as follows:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow; // this should be your value actually
DateTime newTime = dt.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
```

[System.DateTime.Add method documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The AddMinutes method is a better option (The answer by @Ehsan)